# Local Multiplayer new input system is losing device when a new player is connected

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

In my scene there is a boy controlled with a gamepad, and a player input component linked with him.
Then there is an animal companion with a different playerinput component and controls that I want the second gamepad to control.
When the second playerinput component is activated in the scene by activating the gameobject ofthe animal, the first playerinput loses the device in the component.

[image: how it looks the player component]

[image: After I activate the animal gameobject]

I would like to try the
playerInputManager.JoinPlayer(1, -1);
for the second player-animal companion, but when do I activate the second player before of after calling that function, tried both ways and the issue persists?

I can't really use the approach of spawning prefabs since in my case players have different
controls.

Im looking for a coop gameplar similar to:
Spiritfarer
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pKJ-NuSjNE

```
 public void ActivateAnimalCompanion()
{
    if (!hasSpawnedAnimal)
    {
        GManagerSingleton.instance.animal.SetActive(false);
        PlayerInput.Instantiate(GManagerSingleton.instance.animalPlayable, 1, "Gamepad1", -1, new[] { Gamepad.all[1] });
        hasSpawnedAnimal = true;
    }}
```

Comment: You need to post the code.  Screen shots will not help if you are doing something in your code. Which is what this would indicated: l. "When the second playerinput component is activated in the scene by activating the gameobject ofthe animal"

Comment: Are you making sure to enable the 2nd input in the 2nd players scene only?

Comment: Ok I found the solution let me post it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

At last I found a solution.
I didn't need playermanagerinput component on the scene.
All I needed was to spawn the animal companion in the scene via this function:

```
PlayerInput.Instantiate(animalCompanion,userindex: 1,controlscheme: "Gamepad2", split screen:-1,devices: new[] { Gamepad.all[1] });
```

This function would automatically assign the second gamepad to the animal companion at the same time as it is spawned on the scene

This would also stop removing the device from the main player.